# Ubuntu as the only option on the boot menu

Tags: boot

So I decided to upgrade my hard drive from a 750 GB hard drive to a brand new 1 TB hard drive. I installed ubuntu 12.10 with no errors and then updated it to 13.04. Then I attempted to install Windows 7 but when I went into the boot options the usual...

1. HDD
2. CD Drive
3. Network

...was gone. Instead it was only.....

1. ubuntu

...nothing else

*If this helps

Laptop specs

i7 Intel® Core i7-3520M

Intel HD 4000 and Nvidia 620M

Comment: Sounds like you have a buggy bios... you may have to reset it.

Comment: I need to find the flash you're the bios :(

Answer (score 0):

Is this in the Grub menu or the BIOS boot menu? I would suggest uninstalling Ubuntu, and installing Windows first. Then reinstall Ubuntu alongside Windows.

Comment: Bios, but I can't select the disc drive to boot cauz its not an option on the boot options. Only ubuntu, nothing else

Comment: Is there anyway to get into the BIOS, like F2 or ESC. If you can get in to the settings you can try changing the boot order, so it will try to boot from usb or cd first.

Comment: Unfortunately no, it just goes straight to ubuntu